Problem with a simple transistor logic circuit
I have a signal that can jump from >2V to ~15V, I want to turn on one of LEDs for each state of the signal.
Circuit A - works fine but D3 doesn't completely turn off, it's always dimly lit, which makes sense because it's feeding Q2 base current.
Circuit B - Works as intended.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Because I have already printed (circuit A), I wanted to ask if there's anything to do to solve the "always dimly lit" problem without making a mess on the PCB.


Replace Q2 with an appropriate N-channel MOSFET. Take care of maximum Vgs and Vds.
